# How to transform a xml to json for the below sample in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, transform, xml-to-json, wso2-esb

I want to convert the below XML into JSON. Please suggest how to do in wso2 esb and what mediators to be used.

### Input XML

```
<root>
  <tag1>LA - First Name , LA - Middle Name , LA - Last name</tag1>
  <tag1value>Sharath Kumar Chakali</tag1value>
</root>
```

Output JSON

---

```
{
  "LA - First Name , LA - Middle Name , LA - Last name" : "Sharath Kumar Chakali"
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. For the next time please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically - try to read the docs, try to do it yourself and ask when something unclear or not working. To be helpful - you may have a look at the [PayloadFactory](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.1.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/payloadFactory-Mediator/) mediator

Comment: Here the xml comes from a DSS output, so we need to transform that DSS response into JSON as given in the sample example.
So, I think PayloadFactory Mediator will not be useful since, the JSON field name and value has to be framed dynamically based on the XML Input

Comment: Then you have to transform DSS and return the json, That is not clear / different in the question

Comment: Basically, if my input xml is as given in the sample example, How to do I transform it to my expected JSON as given in the sample.
In XML input, the fieldName "tag1" has value "LA - First Name , LA - Middle Name , LA - Last name" and fieldName "tag1value" has value "Sharath Kumar Chakali".
So, how do I transform this dynamically in a way that the json fieldName will be the value of the field "tag1" from XML input and its value will be the value from "tag1value"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard transformation. Therefore what I can suggest is try to use a custom implementation for the mapping. You can either use a class mediator or a script mediator for this purpose. Please refer to the documentation on [1], [2] for this.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Script+Mediator

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator